# paypal recurring, which parameter to use in return_url to confirm successful subscription?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I am using paypal with "subscribe" payment type for recurring payments. I get response in ipn as well as in back_url. In back_url I get all my information of transaction via POST. Now I have two questions:-

1. when i get response in back_url by that time, Has paypal done given transaction or first payment is done when I receive first response in  ipn?
2. In my back_url against which parameter should I check to make sure user has subscribed and I should give him access to my site? or Would I need some information from IPN to confirm subscription?

Do I have to check against many variables? There are many candidates

1. 'txn_type'
2. 'subscr_id'
3. 'payer_id
4. 'auth'

I need an expert opinion about which to use?

Response variables that I get in my return_url are:-

```
{"txn_type"=>"subscr_signup", 
"subscr_id"=>"xxx",
 "last_name"=>"buyer",
 "residence_country"=>"US", 
"mc_currency"=>"USD", 
"item_name"=>"dumppy", 
"business"=>"xxx", 
"amount3"=>"12.00",
 "recurring"=>"1", 
"payer_status"=>"verified",
 "payer_email"=>"xxx", 
"first_name"=>"test", 
"receiver_email"=>"xxx",
"payer_id"=>"xxx",
 "invoice"=>"90", 
"reattempt"=>"1", 
"recur_times"=>"12", 
"subscr_date"=>"21:00:01 Jul 04, 2016 PDT", 
"charset"=>"windows-1252", 
"period3"=>"1 M",
 "mc_amount3"=>"12.00", 
"auth"=>"x",
 "form_charset"=>"UTF-8", 
"controller"=>"xx", 
"action"=>"xxx"}
```

Comment: You shouldn't misuse the return_url for this purpose. You should rely on IPN or another API that is specifically designed to deliver legally binding information.

Comment: IPN sometimes get delayed but I want subscribed user to log in instantly and I cannot tell user that I am waiting for IPN response or else he will leave my site.